# How to pass a plist string (html file name) via table view to detailviewcontroller's webview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, detailsview

I have been fllowing this example

http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-13-using-property-lists-plists/

I am stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property in your detailViewController, in my case it's webViewController.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *urlString;
```

When your tableView cell is clicked, pass your plist string to your detailViewController, by setting this property. Sample code:

```
  WebViewController *webViewController = [WebViewController new];
  webViewController.urlString = urlString;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

That's all, now your detailViewController knows this passed string.

Comment: I have posted my trouble here in another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264665/trouble-loading-html-file-in-webview-of-detailview-using-plist-and-tableviw